# NoClassDefFoundError when using a Maven project in an Android app

Tags: android, maven

Everything of a Maven projected imported to Eclipse appears to be fine. This Maven project has been added to an Android app's build path. The app can be built without any problem.  However, whenever a class of the Maven project is instantiated, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occurs. For testing, here is a simple class:

```
package com.my.maven;
public class Foo {

    public String sFoo;
    public Foo ()
    {
        sFoo = "Foo";
    }
}
```

Whenever the app reaches the following statement:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

The following error occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.maven.Foo
```

There are a lot of posts about NoClassDefFoundError, and I have spent a lot of time reading and trying the solutions, but none has worked.

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: Project -> Properties -> Maven -> uncheck "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects"

Comment: @Milos, I tried that before.  I tried it again a moment ago, and it still did not make any difference.  I always clean the project after making any changes to ensure the changes take effect.

Comment: @Ahmad, the Maven project is added to the build configuration as a project, not a jar file.  Exporting the Maven project as a jar file will be my next step, an undesirable one, if I can not make the current configuration work.

Comment: @Hong, could you please show a printscreen of your project, to see how did you inserted the maven one into the android app.

Comment: Yesterday I received NoClassDefFoundError, which was due to reference project was missing. Check if any reference is missing.

Comment: @Milos, it is added the following way: right-click project > Build Path > Configure Build Path ... > tab Projects > clcik Add.. > check the Maven project > click OK

Comment: You also need check your Maven project in `Build Path - Configure Build Path... - Order and Export`.

Comment: @yokw, I did check it and tried different options (e.g. check or uncheck: 1.Maven Dependences 2. JRE System Library.  Only if both are unchecked, build can work.

Comment: I have exported the Maven project to a jar file, then I added the jar file to the Android project's libs folder.  It works in this way.  This is not desirable because I have to export every time when I made a change to the Maven project.

Comment: Not `Maven Dependencies` nor `JRE System Library`, in `Order and Export` tab, tick the dependency project, i.e. the one you have added in `Projects` tab.

Comment: @yokw  I got you.  It works after checking the Maven project in Or and Export tab of the Android project  I don't know how I missed that part in my exhaustive trial and error effort. Could your write an answer so that I can mark it?  Thanks a lot!